# Adding icon to title bar

Tags: php, css, html, codeigniter

I am trying to put an icon in my website title tag. But its not loading in chrome but is loading in mozilla. i don't know what i am doing wrong?

The link for the image is working correctly.

```
<head>
   <title>Flats in Kochi </title>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url();?> images/melon.ico" type = "image/x-icon"/>
</head>
```

Comment: in which browser are you checking this?

Comment: I'm using google chrome

Comment: A very quick check is to view your pages HTML  source code. What do you see for the code for the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, close the php tag, as Swati mentioned.
Second, add `/` after the php code, so the link tag should be like this:
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/images/melon.ico" />`

Hope it helps you.

Comment: try removing the `type = "image/x-icon"` attribute once.

Answer (score 1):

`<?php echo base_url(); >` here you didn't close php tag ,just change it to `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` ,it should work!

Comment: no, thats not the problem. link is working properly

Comment: @AjayViswanath `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="your_url">` try this.